# From .blend to .mp4

Tags: rendering

finished a test for an animatic but I don't know how to export it as a .mp4 instead of a .blend, I saw that you have to go in "ouput" but I can't find it can someone help me pls

Answer (score 1):

First of all in the output tab of the properties panel choose your video attributes, like size, FPS, container, destination filder, and so on. Then choose "Render Animation" from the render menu.

If the animation is long it's a good idea to render it as PNG or EXR sequence, and then re-render from images (very fast), because if something goes wrong you don't have to start again from the first frame.

[image]